# SQL Count rows for each entity in a column for each month

Tags: mysql, sql

Please refer to attached snapshot. 
**Table0** denotes the structure of the database table which contains the original data. Using SQL, I want to create two tables-- **Table1 and Table2**.

**Table1** should contain the month wise count of **'action_type'=1** for each of the **'make'** values. Similarly, **Table2** contains count for **'action_type'=4**.

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is there a smarter way to generate **Table1** (or Table2)? I am able to accomplish obtaining count for each individual cell shown in **Table1**, but am not able to generate the entire **Table1** at one go
2. I am not able to process the 'created_date' in **mmm-yy** and use that format to generate **Table1** (or Table2)

Comment: Does the full list of possible `make` values is definite and static?

Comment: What is your schema for `table0`, and what is your intended schema for `table1` and `table2`? Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Akina The **make** values are static and non-changing

Comment: Why each month-year is present in desired output twice?

Comment: @Akina yes u r right, it is a typo, sorry. Month-year values are unique in the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`created_date`, '%b-%y') `month`,
       SUM(`make` = 'A') `A`,
       SUM(`make` = 'B') `B`,
       SUM(`make` = 'C') `C`,
       SUM(`make` = 'D') `D`
FROM `Table0`
WHERE `action_type` = 1 /* or another value */
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. I will try the code and let u know.

Comment: Hi Akina, although the '%b-%y' format outputs date in Month-Year format, I see that I am not able to sort the resultant database in ascending order of date. I tried SORT BY ASC but it doesnt work. The month column is sorted alphabetically as per month name. 
  So I see the month column as [Apr-17, Apr-18, August-17, August-18, December-17...] rather than [Apr-17, August-17, December-17, Apr-18, August-18...]. How do I sort the month column chornologically? Further, is it possible to have 4-digit for the year, and not 2-digit (Apr-18 be rather Apr-2018)?

Comment: *How do I sort the month column chornologically?* Use this query as subquery or CTE. Add year and month to output. In main/outer query do not output them, but use them for output sorting. *is it possible to have 4-digit for the year, and not 2-digit (Apr-18 be rather Apr-2018)?* Of course. Use `'%b-%Y'` format.